# How force timestamp of folders recursevely with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

With PowerShell i use this script:

```
$item =  Get-ChildItem -force -recurse | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer} 
foreach($object in $item)
{
     $object.CreationTime=("31 December 2019 23:59:59")
     $object.LastWriteTime=("31 December 2019 23:59:59")
     $object.LastAccessTime=("31 December 2019 23:59:59")
}
```

And it change timestamp for file only but not has effects on folders. How i can fix it, so which too timestamp of folders is update? 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your code you are filtering out directories with `| Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer}`, the function will not do anything on folders.

You can simplify the code using something like this:

```
$date = Get-Date -Year 2019 -Month 12 -Day 31 -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Force -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
     $_.CreationTime   = $date
     $_.LastWriteTime  = $date
     $_.LastAccessTime = $date
}
```

Mind you, the rootfolder (in this example `D:\Test`) itself wil not be affected, only all files and folders **inside** the rootfolder will get new timestamps.

---

As for your question about `LastAccessTime` not being affected:

Windows will automatically update the LastAccessTime on directories when listed in Explorer. This is handles by a registry setting.
It is possible to turn off that feature by setting this registry entry to `1`
 (Default value is `0`)

- **`0`** When listing directories, NTFS updates the last-access timestamp on each directory it detects, and it records each time change in the NTFS log.
- **`1`** When listing directories, NTFS does not update the last-access timestamp, and it does not record time stamp updates in the NTFS log.

To **disable** the automatic update of the LastAccessTime on directories:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate -Value 1 -Type DWord
```

To **(re)enable** the default behaviour:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

Possible values for NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate

```
0 - User Managed, Last Access Updates Enabled
1 - User Managed, Last Access Updates Disabled
2 - System Managed, Last Access Updates Enabled
3 - System Managed, Last Access Updates Disabled
```

Although in Windows 10 these values have changed to negative values (in hex):

```
0x80000000 - User Managed, Last Access Updates Enabled
0x80000001 - User Managed, Last Access Updates Disabled
0x80000002 - System Managed, Last Access Updates Enabled
0x80000003 - System Managed, Last Access Updates Disabled
```

[LastAccessTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc781134(v%3dws.10)#last-access-time)

Hope that explains somewhat

Comment: Thanks. Just a question. Becouse not has effects on LastAccessTime? Is normal it?

Comment: @MarcelloImpastato Please see my edit in which I hope to explain the automatic update of the LastAccessTime property.